# PHPMyAdmin is throwing error on foreign key setup

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, localhost

I have two tables as below

1 : 
Table Name : parent 
Columns : parent_id(Primary Key) , title

2 : 
Table Name : child
Columns : child_id(Primary Key) , title , fk_pid(Indexed)

I want to make reference between `prent.parent_id` and `child.fk_pid` . I have set type of both table to InnoDB. I have opened 'relation view' in the structure of child table. Then I have selected foreign key constraint for `child.fk_pid` and set to `parent.parent_id` and set options as below

constraint name : myFK
on delete : restrict
on update : restrict

but when I am clicking on save button, PHPMyAdmin is throwing following error.

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fk`.`#sql-168_5f`, CONSTRAINT `myFk` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_pid`) REFERENCES `parent` (`parent_id`))
```

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL won't create the foreign key if you have fk_pid in the child table that don't exist as id in the parent table. Check the child table for any references to a parent id that do not exist in the parent table.

```
select fk_pid from child left join parent on child.fk_pid = parent.id where parent.id is null;
```